# matlab spectogram function

Tags: matlab, signals

I am using matlab to generate a chirp signal frequency between 35000 Hz and 45000 Hz. I want to use the spectogram function to monitor the change in frequency overtime, but I dont know how to use this function. Any help?

```
freqSamp = 96000;
tStart = 0;
tEnd = 1;
t = tStart:1/freqSamp:tEnd;

freqStart = 35000;
freqEnd = 45000;
phaseInit = -90;
method = 'linear';
y = chirp(t, freqStart, tEnd, freqEnd, method, phaseInit);

spectrogram(x, , , ,96000,'yaxis')
```

Comment: [`help spectrogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) would probably be a good start

Comment: `spectrogram(y, 1024, [], [], 96000, 'yaxis')` produces a nice picture. You can experiment with other input valies